# Calculating ROI for marketing media spend for use linear optimisation

Tags: regression, linear

I want to be able to calculate the optimal budget allocations for a number of media channels (TV, display, social) with regards to a KPI (revenue). I want to be able to use linear optimisation, similar to this example found here https://rpubs.com/PE_Stat/569796

However I firstly need to be able to calculate the ROI for each channel. Is there a standard way of doing this? Thus far I have been using linear optimisation, which does seem to work well generally. However I sometimes get certain variables with negative coefficients from the regression, meaning that they have a negative effect on the KPI, which most likely is not the case. Are there any alternative methods I could use to overcome this problem in calculating ROI?